# IE Back Button 404 from SharePoint Provider Hosted App Chrome Control Settings Link

Tags: add-in, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint provider hosted app. The Chrome control is configured and seems to be working correctly. I've configured a single settings with the following options:

```
var options = {
        "appTitle": document.title,
        "appStartPage": "/?" + queryString,
        "onCssLoaded": "QuotationApprovalsApp.chromeLoaded();",
        "siteTitle": "Test",
        "settingsLinks": [
            {
                "linkUrl": "/Test?" + queryString,
                "displayName": "Test"
            }
        ]
    };
```

The linkUrl goes to a test page in my application. This works and looks fine. Clicking the back button in the browser results in this:

[image: Broken links]

Any idea why back button causes this? In IE developer toolbar, I see the following error:

404 error
Key Value
Request GET /__browserLink/requestData/0055c17ab05b44599accaf6714a5604b?version=2 HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding SPHostTitle to the Query string in AppManifest fixed this issue:

[image]